# SQL ORACLE ERROR: integrity constraint (********.FK_COUR_O_POD) violated - parent key not found

Tags: sql, oracle

I am receiving this error when trying to insert a record

**error message**

> Error at line 1: ORA-02291: integrity constraint
>   (S7671318.FK_COUR_O_POD) violated - parent key not found

**insert query**

```
INSERT INTO PRODUCTS_OFFERED(ProdID,CourseID,DateOffered)
    VALUES ('X08','LB04', TO_DATE('2015/01/27', 'yyyy/mm/dd'))
```

**cause**

Caused by the constraint :

```
CREATE TABLE PRODUCTS_OFFERED   (   ProdID Varchar2(6)
, CourseID Varchar2(6)
, DateOffered Date
, CONSTRAINT PK_PRODUCTS_OFFERED PRIMARY KEY(ProdID,CourseID,DateOffered)
, CONSTRAINT FK_PROMPROD FOREIGN KEY (ProdID) 
     REFERENCES PROMOTIONAL_PRODUCTS
, CONSTRAINT FK_COUR_O_POD FOREIGN KEY (CourseID,DateOffered) 
     REFERENCES COURSE_OFFERING /// This constraint here.
);
```

I am unsure the solution to this. Note: this is a weak entity borrowing a composite identifier combined between a borrowed key and a entity attribute.

Comment: the error message references which constraint is in error [ `FK_COUR_O_POD` ] : in this case its objecting to writing a record to `PRODUCTS_OFFERED` without there being an record in `COURSE_OFFERING` with `CourseID` and `DateOffered`..

Comment: You can fix this by adding the appropriate record to `Course_Offering`.